# Can it be the case that my 10-year old smoke alarm wiring has an interconnect cable?

Tags: electrical, wiring, smoke-detectors

Our house was completely re-wired and new wired smoke alarms installed in 2010. The smoke alarms were not interconnected.  There are four wires: brown, gray, black, sleeveless.

Now I am installing an interconnected system. Is it possible that there is an interconnect cable in the 2010 wiring?  As far as I can tell, brown = live, gray = neutral, sleeveless = earth. What could black be other than an interconnect cable?

Comment: in north america our smoke alarms are interconnected using 14/3 wiring and the colors are white/black and red.  where are you located?

Comment: i had some wired up in 2006 and they were interconnected so yes 10 years ago they could have been wired up as interconnected.

Comment: Mine were interconnected in 1996. I am in NZ.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments.  I am in Scotland.  So it looks like the additional cable is the interconnect cable, which would make it the one part of the house that was built to a higher spec than absolutely necessary.